# Do classes with static methods get Garbage collected?

Tags: java, c#, android, garbage-collection

Say i have a class 'Test' which has number of static methods.

```
class Test {
  public static T BytesToInt<T>(){ 
    //Logic
  }
  public static void Parse(string data){
    //
  }
}
```

I create large number of instances of Test class. Will these objects be garbage collected?

Comment: Your `Parse` method doesn't return anything, so there's nothing to collect as a result of calling it. Your other method returns a generic T. If T is a reference type, and, as @vinnygray points out, if no other objects holds a reference to that object then it will be eligible for collection. None of this has anything to do with how many instances of `Test` you create. It all has to do with how.many instance of objects of reference types (/classes) no longer have other object referring to them. In general, you don't need to think about this, it usually *Just Works*.

Comment: Oh, and it has nothing to do with how many methods a class has, whether they are public, private, static or non-static.

Answer (score 4):

Yes. As long as nothing is holding a reference to them they will be collected

Answer (score 1):

Yes, when any `Test` instance out of scope or no longer referenced it would be eligible for `GC`. In general, instance means object created with constructor for example `new Test()`, and resides in heap area. Not to be confused with `static` members of which are class method.

Refer static method section in JLS below for more details:-

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.3.2